# How do I Automate BIng Maps data upload?

Tags: automation, upload, maps, bing-maps, bing

How do I upload data to Bing Maps without having to use the portal? I can’t find anything in the documentation that mentions this, but any time we update our data, I have to manually upload a new XML file. Ideally, we would automate the upload whenever we update the data.

The *closest* I can get is the [Uploading Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/getting-started/bing-maps-dev-center-help/geocoding-and-managing-data-sources/uploading-and-publishing-entity-data-to-a-data-source) page, but there's nothing there about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the data source management API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/spatial-data-services/data-source-management-api/

If you are working in .NET, you might also find this library useful: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsSDSToolkit

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try